# How do I build nested objects from sql query

Tags: java, sql

I've got a query which returns data from several tables. In the application, these tables are classes one within another, for example a Client has several Orders, each Order has several OrderDetails, each OrderDetail has several Products, and so on... But I can't figure out a proper way to build the entire object in the app since the query returns one row for (let's just say) each product, so I have one client repeated over and over for every product it has bought.

So far I've tried this terribly inefficient code, and it works, problem is, it takes too much time for the app to process all of this information when it retrieves several clients.

```
 boolean orderFound = false;
                for (Order order1 : orders) {
                    if (order1 .getId() == order.getId()) {
                        orderFound = true;
                        if (od.getId() != 0) {
                            boolean odFound = false;

         for (OrderDetail orderdetail : order1.getOrderDetail()) {
                                if (orderDetail.getId() == od.getId()) {
                                    if (prod.getId() != 0) {
                                        odFound = true;
                                        boolean prodFound= false;
                                        for (Product product: orderDetail.getProducts()) {
                                            if (product.getId() == product.getId()) {
                                                prodFound= true;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if (!prodFound) {
                                            orderDetail.getProducts().add(dia);
                                        }
                                    }

                            if (!odFound) {
                                order1.getOrderDetail().add(od);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!orderFound) {
                    if (order.getId() != 0) {
                        orders.add(order);
```

This works, but there's gotta be a better way and I haven't found it. I've been told this can be solved using HashSets but I still don't know how to use them. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are open to using third party libraries, I think this is what you are looking for:
[How to use hibernate to query for an object with a nested object that has a nested collection of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36976226/how-to-use-hibernate-to-query-for-an-object-with-a-nested-object-that-has-a-nest)

Comment: Yes, I am open to whatever helps this process go faster, thanks, I will definitely give it a try